# Setting the 'active tab' before rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

When the component was rendered, I had already set the `active tab` in `this.setState({activeTab: response.data[0].id})`.

```
componentDidMount() {
   axios.get
        axios({
            url, 
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
              scores: response.data,
              activeTab: response.data[0].id,   
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("User not enrolled.", error);
        })     
}
```

But when I added `socket.io`,`this.setState ({})`it updates every few seconds. When the component is rendered, tab `0` is active. I click on tab `2`, then under the influence of sockets, after a few seconds it automatically returns to tab`0`. How to set it so that it does not automatically return to tab `0`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    socket.on("FromAPI", data => this.setState({ 
      scores: data,
      activeTab: data[0].id
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Your server seems to emit some "FromAPI" events ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes; I fetch dates to array `scores`

Comment: Consider if setting the tab by response is really what you want to achieve. Every time when the event comes the component set the active tab based on the response, so you have to put more logic here